# Give an element a default height, but force it to shrink to fit inside its parent (only allow it to overflow if it hits a specified min-height)

Tags: html, css, position

Say I have the following set up:

- Some header text
- a content div

Inside one parent div.

```css
.outer {
  max-height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.inner {
  min-height: 50px;
  /*for demonstration, the default height is set to a value greater than the outer's max-height. Normally, this wouldn't be the case intially */
  height: 250px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span> Hi!</span>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <!-- Placing a footer here, only to demonstrate that the content overflows (the background would be green, if it was inside the parent div) -->
  <!-- You can ignore the existence of the footer in your answer -->
  <span> bye! </span>
</div>
```

On the content div, I would like to specify a default height. However, imagine that the header text is actually a div, and its height may expand dynamically, pushing the content downwards.

This will cause the content to overflow eventually.

Rather than having the content overflow, I would like the inner div to shrink to fit within its parent's max-height, until the inner div hits its min-height, then it can overflow.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Flexbox. [Flexbox browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

**Flexbox Solution:**

```css
.outer {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.inner {
    background-color: pink;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <span> Header! <br /> <br /> <br /> Line Breaks to demonstrate a tall header.</span>
  <div class="inner"><p>On the content div, I would like to specify a default height. However, imagine that the header text is actually a div, and its height may expand dynamically, pushing the content downwards.</p>
  <p>This will cause the content to overflow eventually.</p>
<p>Rather than having the content overflow, I would like the inner div to shrink to fit within its parent's max-height, until the inner div hits its min-height, then it can overflow.</p> </div>
  <!-- Placing a footer here, only to demonstrate that the content overflows (the background would be green, if it was inside the parent div) -->
  <!-- You can ignore the existence of the footer in your answer -->
  <span> Footer! </span>
</div>
```